# Creating ArcMap Versions using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, versioning

Why doesn't the script break if the Version exists?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\jnmiller\Desktop\Create User Version.py", line 30, in 
>       arcpy.CreateVersion_management(sdeConnection, parentVersion, versionName, "PROTECTED")
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 18244, in CreateVersion
>       raise e
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 001148: Cannot create a version with the specified name.
>   Failed to execute (CreateVersion).

```
# Name: SDE_CreateVersion
# Description: Creates a new SDE version

# Import system modules
import arcpy, time, smtplib, os

# Set local variables
sdeConnection = "Database Connections\NEO_1.sde"
parentVersion = "sde.DEFAULT"
versionName = os.environ.get( "USERNAME" )

fullPath = os.path.join("Windows Credentials: EGAS", versionName)
existingVersion = os.path.join("Version Currently Exists: ",versionName)
createVersion = os.path.join("Version Created: ",versionName)

print("Searching for User Credentials..")
time.sleep(2)
print(fullPath)
time.sleep(3)
print("Checking SDE for existing Credentials..")

for version in arcpy.da.ListVersions(sdeConnection):
    if version.name.split(".")[0] == versionName:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(existingVersion)
        time.sleep(5)
        break
    else:
        # Execute CreateVersion
        arcpy.CreateVersion_management(sdeConnection, parentVersion, versionName, "PROTECTED")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(createVersion)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't make sense: listing existing versions to create them can't work. While you can use any user's version, you cannot create anthing but your own, so periods are not permitted in the name string (31 chars max, leading alpha, remainder alphanumeric)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It fails because the version creation block is inside the loop over existing version. As it is now, the code loads the list of version, reads the name of the 1st one, and if the owner is different than the one in `versionName`, it creates the version.

To fix it, you must move the version creation block outside of the loop. You create a flag variable `versionFound` that you set to `false` by default, and to `true` if the version is found. Later, if `versionFound == False`, you can safely create the new version

```
versionFound = False
for version in arcpy.da.ListVersions(sdeConnection):
    if version.name.split(".")[0] == versionName:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(existingVersion)
        time.sleep(5)
        versionFound = True
        break


# Execute CreateVersion
if not versionFound:
        arcpy.CreateVersion_management(sdeConnection, parentVersion, versionName, "PROTECTED")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(createVersion)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Making users wait for nothing with all the `sleep` is not considered as best practices.